# Как я могу напечатать список в гриде 3x3? 1 - Python

Tags: python, массивы, list

```
import random

list0 = list()

for i in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
      r = random.randint(1, 9)
      list0.append(r)
    
for item in list0:
  print(item, end=' ')
```

Я хочу написать его в сетке 3х3.
Kак я могу это сделать ?

Comment: `list0 = [[random.randint(1, 9) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, item in enumerate(list0, 1):
    print(item, end=' ')
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print()
```

Или, если использовать тернарный оператор:

```
for i, item in enumerate(list0, 1):
    print(item, end='\n' if i % 3 == 0 else ' ')
```